# Not able to start up hyperledger fabric network

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I'm getting below error when running command `./fabricNetwork.sh up`.

**error**

```
Error : manifest for hyperledger/fabric-ca:latest not found
Error : no such container : cli
```

**errror screenshot**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DXSIz.jpg

**docker files**

https://github.com/NavyaGouru/Ashish_HLF

Answer (score 2):

Try `hyperledger/fabric-ca:1.4.8`. `latest` tag has been deprecated instead use a specific tag. Fix your `Local Image` and `Docker Image` error too by updating `Local Images` to `1.4.8`.

Comment: Local images to be updated in which file ? configtx.yaml ?

Answer (score 0):

@alpha as already answered the question. I'd just like to add one point to it. You can pass the image tag to be used to launch the network using `-i` to the command. Its default value `latest`. You can see this by passing the `--help` flag to the command `./fabricNetwork.sh up`.

The `Local Version` of the images can be found in the `.env` file in the directory. `DOCKER_IMAGE_VERSION` is the version that you pass using the `-i` flag. These two should have the same value otherwise you'll get this.

```
=================== WARNING ===================
  Local fabric binaries and docker images are
  out of  sync. This may cause problems.
===============================================
ERROR! Fabric Docker image version of 1.4.8 does not match the versions supported by the test network.
```